# testing-library-react: asserting class exists (for styling purposes)

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

From what I understand about `testing-library-react`, one should avoid using `container.querySelector` because the whole point of the testing library is to test mostly "as the user does." I'm on board with this, but what is the proper way, if any, to test that a class name (for actual styling purposes) is applied to a `<p>` tag for example?

In my specific example, the text should be one of three colors, based on a priority. So I'd like to test to ensure that not only does the correct text exist, but it should up in the correct color.

```
const SomeComponent = ({ priority }) => {
  const priorityClass = priorityEvaluator(priority); # returns class with "color: red, green, or yellow"
  return (
    <p className={priorityClass}>Some text</p>
  )
)}
```

In the test:

```
test("something", () => async {
  const { findByText } = render(<SomeComponent />);
  expect(findByText("Some text").toBeTruthy();
  # assert text is the proper color?
})
```

Is the preferred way to use `jest-dom`'s `toHaveStyle`/`toHaveClass` and target the element by the `testid` data attribute? Or is there a better way?

Comment: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohaveclass?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test a className with Jest and React testing library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53389956/how-to-test-a-classname-with-jest-and-react-testing-library)